# Flutter: Filter hitevent for specific PointerDeviceKind and only absorb these

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, stylus, hittest

I am trying to read the stylus with a "global" listener, while still being able to interact with the rest of the UI with the finger. The event object passed to the listeners of the `Listener` widget actually has a property for the device kind, but I can't tell it which events to absorb and which not to. You can only specify it for every event with `HitTestBehavior`, but this is not what I want.

I tried a bit to reverse engineer the `Listener` widget, but it doesn't seem to be possible to know the pointer device kind at the point where you have to decide whether to fire a hit. And I also could not find out how to cancel an event in the `handleEvent` callback provided by `RenderObject` or something like that.

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (event) {
    if (!pointerKinds.contains(event.kind)) return;
    // Absorb now
    ...
  },
);
```

```dart
class _SomeRenderObject extends RenderProxyBox {
  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event, covariant HitTestEntry entry) {
    if(event.kind != PointerDeviceKind.stylus) {
      // Cancel event
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the mechanism I was searching for is built on `Listener` and is called [gesture-disambiguation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/gestures#gesture-disambiguation).
Its API is exposed through `RawGestureDetector` and `GestureRecognizer`s. These are used under the hood of `GestureDetector` for example. `Listener` itself is actually rarely used to listen to events.

A `GestureRecognizer` needs to decide whether or not some user interaction fits a specific gesture and when it does fit, it can claim any pointers that it needs, so no other `GestureRecognizer` can claim these pointers.

There are already many implementations available in flutter, like `DragGestureRecognizer` and it turns out, they already can filter for specific `PointerDeviceKind`s. The Constructor has a `supportedDevices` property you can use. But for some reason, you can't use it in `GestureDetector` directly, but you have to use `RawGestureDetector`, where you have to construct the `GestureRecognizer`s yourself. Here is an example:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Map<Type, GestureRecognizerFactory> gestures = {
    DragGestureRecognizer:
        GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<DragGestureRecognizer>(
      () => DragGestureRecognizer(supportedDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.stylus})
        ..onStart = _onStart
        ..onUpdate = _onUpdate
        ..onEnd = _onEnd,
      (instance) => instance
        ..onStart = _onStart
        ..onUpdate = _onUpdate
        ..onEnd = _onEnd,
    ),
  };

  return RawGestureDetector(
    child: child,
    gestures: gestures,
  );
}
```

It is a bit more Boilerplate involved thou!

But I went a bit further because I didn't want the drag gesture to start, after the pointer has moved, but rather to start in the moment, the pointer touches the screen, and implemented my own `GestureRecognizer` (based on what I found in `DragGestureRecognizer`):

```dart
class InstantDragGestureRecognizer extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {
  GestureDragStartCallback? onStart;
  GestureDragUpdateCallback? onUpdate;
  GestureDragEndCallback? onEnd;

  Duration? _startTimestamp;

  late OffsetPair _initialPosition;

  int? _pointer;

  InstantDragGestureRecognizer({
    Object? debugOwner,
    Set<PointerDeviceKind>? supportedDevices,
  }) : super(supportedDevices: supportedDevices);

  @override
  String get debugDescription => "instant-drag";

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {
    _pointer = null;
    _checkEnd(pointer);
  }

  // called for every event that involves a pointer, tracked by this recognizer
  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    _startTimestamp = event.timeStamp;
    if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      _checkUpdate(
        sourceTimeStamp: event.timeStamp,
        delta: event.localDelta,
        primaryDelta: null,
        globalPosition: event.position,
        localPosition: event.localPosition,
      );
    }
    if (event is PointerUpEvent || event is PointerCancelEvent) 
      stopTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
  }

  // new pointer touches the screen and needs to be registered for gesture 
  // tracking, override [isPointerAllowed] to define, which pointer is valid for 
  // this gesture
  @override
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    if (_pointer != null) return;
    super.addAllowedPointer(event);
    // claim tracked pointers
    resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    _pointer = event.pointer;
    _initialPosition = OffsetPair(global: event.position, local: event.localPosition);
  }

  // called after pointer was claimed
  @override
  void acceptGesture(int pointer) {
    _checkStart(_startTimestamp!, pointer);
  }

  // copied from [DragGestureRecognizer]
  void _checkStart(Duration timestamp, int pointer) {
    if (onStart != null) {
      final DragStartDetails details = DragStartDetails(
        sourceTimeStamp: timestamp,
        globalPosition: _initialPosition.global,
        localPosition: _initialPosition.local,
        kind: getKindForPointer(pointer),
      );
      invokeCallback<void>('onStart', () => onStart!(details));
    }
  }

  // copied from [DragGestureRecognizer]
  void _checkUpdate({
    Duration? sourceTimeStamp,
    required Offset delta,
    double? primaryDelta,
    required Offset globalPosition,
    Offset? localPosition,
  }) {
    if (onUpdate != null) {
      final DragUpdateDetails details = DragUpdateDetails(
        sourceTimeStamp: sourceTimeStamp,
        delta: delta,
        primaryDelta: primaryDelta,
        globalPosition: globalPosition,
        localPosition: localPosition,
      );
      invokeCallback<void>('onUpdate', () => onUpdate!(details));
    }
  }

  // copied from [DragGestureRecognizer]
  void _checkEnd(int pointer) {
    if (onEnd != null) {
      invokeCallback<void>('onEnd', () => onEnd!(DragEndDetails(primaryVelocity: 0.0)));
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually a really nice way of implementing gesture disambiguation! One benefit of using flutter, but some more documentation on how to write gesture recognizers would be great!